# producer-consumer c - segmentation fault for bigger values

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, segmentation-fault, producer-consumer

I am doing the one producer-one consumer problem with two threads in c. I did it using a shared linked list in which producer puts something and consumer takes it from the same list. 
I have to run my code with 2 values N and B(N being the size of data to be transferred and B being the maximum size of the shared linked list). 
(./thread-a1 N B)
This code runs fine for small values. But, for N = 20,000 and B = 16, it gives Segmentation fault: 11
I cannot figure out why is this happening. Please help

```
#include<time.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>

struct job
{
    int data;
    struct job* next;
};

struct job* head;
int maxSize;
int n;
pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int getCount()
{
    int count = 0;
    struct job* p = head;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        p = p -> next;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

void Insert(int x)
{

    struct job* temp = (struct job*)malloc(sizeof(struct job));
    temp -> data = x;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        temp -> next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        temp -> next = head;
    }
    head = temp;
}

void Delete()
{

    struct job *toDelete, *secondLastNode;

    if(head == NULL)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        toDelete = head;
        secondLastNode = head;


        while(toDelete->next != NULL)
        {

            secondLastNode = toDelete;
            toDelete = toDelete->next;
        }
        printf("%d, ", toDelete -> data);

        if(toDelete == head)
        {
            free(toDelete);
            head = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            secondLastNode->next = NULL;
            free(toDelete);
        }

    }
}

void* producer(void* arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    head = NULL; 

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {

        while(getCount() >= maxSize)
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
        }
        Insert(i);
    }

    return NULL;
}

void* consumer(void* arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        while(getCount() <= 0)
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);   
        }
        Delete();
    }


    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    struct timeval start_init, end_init;
    gettimeofday(&start_init, NULL);
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    maxSize = atoi(argv[2]);

    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;
    gettimeofday(&end_init, NULL);
    printf("Time elapsed for initialization is: %ld\n", 
        (long)(end_init.tv_sec*1000000 + end_init.tv_usec) -    (start_init.tv_sec*1000000 + start_init.tv_usec));

    struct timeval start_trans, end_trans;
    gettimeofday(&start_trans, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &producer, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &consumer, NULL);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    gettimeofday(&end_trans, NULL);
    printf("Time elapsed for transmission is: %ld\n", 
        (long)(end_trans.tv_sec*1000000 + end_trans.tv_usec) - (start_trans.tv_sec*1000000 + start_trans.tv_usec));


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where in the program does the segfault occur?

Comment: You should check the return value of `malloc`. If it is zero, you are out of memory.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: I don't think 20K very small structs will exhaust memory, even if none of them are ever freed.

Comment: @ScottHunter: sometimes when it starts running, or sometimes in between while running

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: I added a condition statement that if malloc returns 0, program returns. But, the fault still occurs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to revisit your locking; you only acquire locks at the start of each producer & consumer, and from then on only unlock them (repeatedly!), meaning no further synchronization happens.  The longer your program runs, the more likely that this lack of synchronization will trip up your program.

Comment: In addition to this, you should also read some about 'busy waiting' and how to avoid it.

Comment: @SukhmanWaraich It is an error to attempt to unlock a mutex which is already unlocked. Putting the `pthread_mutex_unlock` call in a loop as you have it is only going to lead to trouble: https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock

Comment: As @johni said.  In particular, a condition variable would be a good choice here, or maybe a pair of semaphores.

Comment: @ScottHunter: Even if I remove all the locks, the error occurs

Comment: Don't *remove* the locks; use them (or some other mechanism) properly.

Comment: got it. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your locking should be:

```
void* producer(void* arg)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
        while(getCount() >= maxSize)
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);   // allow consumer to acquire lock
            pthread_mutex_lock(&m);     // re-acquire lock
        }
        Insert(i);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void* consumer(void* arg)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
        while(getCount() <= 0)
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);   // allow producer to acquire lock  
            pthread_mutex_lock(&m);     // re-acquire lock
        }
        Delete();
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Note that all operations, including `getCount`, must be done with the lock acquired. (Consider also replacing `getCount` with a global variable; only manipulate it while locked.)

Comment: Thanks Paul. I got it